# aspell - how to ignore references inside \citep{} and \citet{} references

Tags: linux, spelling

I'm using `aspell --version`
International Ispell Version 3.1.20 (but really Aspell 0.60.6)
to verify my tex files with the command:

```
aspell -d pt_PT --dont-tex-check-comments  -c file0.tex
```

The problem is that ispell checks inside each

```
\citep{someone2011sometitle}
```

and each

```
\citet{someone2011sometitle}
```

that I'm using with

```
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
```

What can I do for ispell to ignore the references?

Comment: Very old versions involved here => 'too localized'.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The manual says that you need to add the following to the command line:

```
--add-tex-command citep op --add-tex-command citet op
```

Here op means that each command (`\citet` or `\citep`) may have one optional parameter and has one mandatory parameter, and neither should be checked (if you want to check the optional one, use Op instead).

See http://aspell.net/0.50-doc/man-html/4_Customizing.html

Update:  the proper syntax (for some versions of aspell?) might be

```
--add-tex-command="citep op" --add-tex-command="citet op"
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I browsed the documentation but didn't figure out how to do this.  Sill, in my system, I had to do --add-tex-command="citep op" (with the = sign and with quotes).

Comment: I think the manual might be wrong here, and the ="..." is the right one...

Answer (score 16):

To add the setting to the configuration file (`/etc/aspell.conf` or `~/.aspell.conf`), you don't need the quotes:

```
add-tex-command citep op
add-tex-command citet op
```