# Spell check package for writeLaTeX.com

Tags: packages, spelling, overleaf

I use [writeLaTeX](https://www.writelatex.com/) to create my Tex documents. It's great, it has a dynamic preview which works much better than any other latex software I have seen, and as your files are saved online so you can easily access your documents from any computer.

The one problem is that it does not include a spell check with the free version. Is there a usepackage that does a spell check?

Thanks!

Comment: My, that would be interesting. It would only reliably work on Unix-based machines though (at least how I'm thinking about it; I've no idea where dictionaries are stored under Windows) and it would be *awfully* slow—but it could work.  Your *best* approach would be to just use a browser with spell-check though (or some kind of plugin that can penetrate through writeLaTeX's 'defenses' in this case).

Comment: I use chrome, which has a spell check, but it doesn't work on write latex. Another problem is it would also think that commands are spelling errors. It has to only check the text parts.

Comment: I don't have the time nor the technical know-how to implement this, but you could read everything from the dictionary into a token list and then, at every word boundary (this is where it gets hairy), grab the last word (up unto the last word boundary) and check for its existence in the token list.  Perhaps someone more skilled that I can implement this as an answer :) (assuming there isn't a smarter way)

Comment: As an alternative you could try www.ShareLatex.com which is almost the same. However, as I remember they do include the spell checker in the free plan. ShareLatex does also allow you to sync (two way) your projects to your DropBox account and not only for backup (one way).

Comment: A proper LaTeX *package* for spelling check highlighting in the resulting PDF would be an interesting feature.

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Is there a spell check package for LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42843/5699)