# Command line based spellcheckers for ConTeXt files on Windows

Tags: context, languages, spelling, spell

**Note: I'm crossposting from the [mailing list](https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2022/105396.html) and [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/LaTeX/comments/tudcfn/command_line_based_spellcheckers_for_context/)**

I'm currently using ConTeXt on a windows machine. I'd like to incorporate some sort of automated spell-checking in my workflow. I've seen that there are two options:

1. spell check the `.tex` source file
2. spell check the resulting pdf

For the first option many resources online seem to suggest using `aspell`. `aspell` is however not maintained for windows and therefore hopelessly out of date. Furthermore many resources online seem to suggest skipping TeX and LaTeX control sequences does not always succeed. So I can only imagine how poorly it deals with ConTeXt control sequences.

The second option as shown on [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42843/is-there-a-spell-check-package-for-latex) StackExchange post suggests using `\loadspellchecklist`. However, on of the arguments to this command includes a text file listing - and brace yourself - *all of the correctly spelled words*. I find this both an amusing and tragic proposition, since I basically need to spellcheck based on every word in a given language.

What options are out there for someone who would like to do serious spellchecking using ConTeXt on Windows platform, using Powershell as my command line?

Comment: What, exactly, do you think a ”dictionary“ (at least in the context of spell-checking) is other than a list of correctly spelled words? Add a few rules allowing for inflection and compound words (not much of an issue with English), and there you have it. I am using `LuaLaTeX`, not `ConTeXt`, but `hunspell` handles that just fine. I am sure `aspell` (How can a spell checker be ”hopelessly out of date“, I wonder?) would be up to the task as well.

Comment: A dictionary might well be a list of words, but its not much use when I have to make one from scratch, which is what the ConTeXt docs seem to suggest

Comment: Obviously that work’s been done. For English I recommend http://wordlist.aspell.net/

Comment: My workflow is to edit in Markdown, convert Markdown to XHTML, then typeset the XHTML using ConTeXt's XML parser. That allows using the spell checker bundled with whatever Markdown editor you prefer. More concretely, I edit in my [KeenWrite](https://github.com/DaveJarvis/keenwrite/#download) editor, which underlines spelling mistakes and can fix them with `Alt+Enter` followed by `Enter`. Typesetting using ConTeXt is then accomplished with `Ctrl+p`, followed by pressing `Enter` a few times.